# an unhandled exception occured while tried to send a mail in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sendmail

when i tried to send a mail i got these exceptions

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Transaction failed. The server response
>   was: 5.7.7 Sender Unknown in Local Domain . at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode,
>   String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection
>   conn, Byte[] command, String from) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify,
>   SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   _Default.Button1_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\pjt\mail_check\Default.aspx.cs:line 39

Comment: and is the sender known in the local domain?

Comment: @pleun i need to know that what is this means:"The server response was: 5.7.7 Sender Unknown in Local Domain "